# SELECT in multiple tables

Tags: mysql, select

I have this 3 tables:

```
POST [id_post, url]
CAT [id_cat, name]
POST_CAT [id_post, id_cat]
```

I have 10-15 categories, and between 100-200 urls to each category, but the problem is the urls can have more than one category, then... i want show ALL categories with 1 url, but that url can't be showed in the other categories

How can i do?

I have this SQL but obviously don't do what i want:

```
SELECT c.nombre, p.url 
FROM post_cat pc, posts p, categorias c
WHERE pc.id_post = p.id_post 
AND c.id = pc.id_cat 
GROUP BY pc.id_cat
```

Thank you and sorry for my bad english!!!

--------–--------–--------–--------–--------–

```
Data (Example): 

CAT 1 - URL1, URL2
CAT 2 - URL1, URL2
CAT 3 - URL2, URL3
CAT 4 - URL1, URL2
```

What this show:

```
CAT1 - URL1
CAT2 - URL2
CAT3 - URL3
```

CAT4 - URL1 (cause URL1 and URL2 is shown in other categories... show 1 of them independent if is repeated or not)

Comment: Is the c) a typo?  There should be no ) there.

Comment: Would you please provide some sample data and expected output?

Comment: I'm also going to assume you translated nombre in the first example.  So as I see it, if you remove the GROUP BY it will have URL | Category Name for every listing of the url.  You only want the URL listed once and every category in the URL?

Comment: nombre is translated (name for you, yes :P) and yes, what you ask is what i need, only 1 url for each category and that URL cannot be repetead in the other categories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a unique url for each category, where that url has no other categories.  Unfortunately, there is no guaranteed solution to this in SQL.  But you can come close.

The first thing is to choose an arbitrary category for each url:

```
select p.url, min(pc.id_cat) as id_cat
FROM post_cat pc join
     posts p
     on pc.id_post = p.id_post 
GROUP BY p.url
HAVING count(*) = 1;
```

The `having` clause guarantees that there is just one category for the `url`.

Next, you want to choose one of these for each category:

```
select id_cat, min(url) as url
from (select p.url, min(pc.id_cat) as id_cat
      FROM post_cat pc join
           posts p
           on pc.id_post = p.id_post 
      GROUP BY p.url
      HAVING count(*) = 1
group by id_cat;
```

If you want additional category information (such as the name), then join in the categories table.
     ) p

Comment: that show only 2 categories with differentes URL, but only 2 categories, i have 10-15 categories aprox

Comment: ok, this show all categories who only have 1 only URL, and i don't need this but thank you to much :)

Comment: @kaseOga . . . You can remove the `having` clause if you want to allow URLs with multiple categories.  It is there because that is how I understood the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try **GROUP_CONCAT()**:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(c.nombre), p.url 
FROM post_cat pc, posts p, categorias c
WHERE pc.id_post = p.id_post 
AND c.id = pc.id_cat 
GROUP BY pc.id_cat
```

This creates one text field containing all values of c.nombre as grouped by your GROUP BY clause.

See here for the full documentation about this:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score 0):

By using Joins you can relate as many tables as you need.  Joins are the heart of relational datebases.

```
Select c.nombre, p.url from post_cat pc join posts p on c.id=pc.id_cat 
join categorias c on pc.id_cat=c.id_cat
```

Also consider the use of `Left Join`, `Right Join`, `Union`.

Comment: The OP is already using joins with post_cat pc, posts p, categorias c.